# Printf Function In For Loop Changes My Array

Tags: c

I try to change my array within for loop. When I print it in the loop, my array changes but when I don't print it in the loop I can not change my array and it gives me random values. Here is the code :

```
double find_mean(double **matrix, int column, int row_count){
    double mean, sum;
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<row_count; i++){
        sum += matrix[i][column];
    }

    mean = sum / row_count;

    return mean;

}

double find_cov(double **matrix, int column1, int column2, int row_count){
    double mean1, mean2, numerator, denominator, result;
    int i;

    numerator = 0;
    denominator = row_count-1;

    mean1 = find_mean(matrix, column1, row_count);
    mean2 = find_mean(matrix, column2, row_count);

    for(i=0; i<row_count; i++){
        numerator += (matrix[i][column1] - mean1) * (matrix[i][column2] - mean2);
    }

    result = numerator / denominator;

    return result;

}

double **calculate_covariance_matrix(double **matrix, int row_count, int row_size) {

    int i, j, x, y;
    double **copy;

    copy = (double **) malloc(sizeof(double *)*row_size);
    for (x=0; x<row_size; x++){
        copy[x] = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double)*row_size);
    }

    i=0;

    while(i<row_size){
        j=0;
        while(j<row_size){
            copy[i][j] = find_cov(matrix, i, j, row_count);
            **printf("%.0lf", copy[i][j]);**
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }


    return copy;

}
```

**Printf** function that i show in bolt style is the problem.

Comment: *"it gives me random values"* - sounds like Undefined Behavior.

Comment: You have undefined behaviour stemming from three instances of using `row_size` where `row_count` should be used.

Comment: Tip: `int j; j=0; while(j<row_size){ ...; j++ }` is a mess. Use one statement with properly-scoped variables: `for (int j=0; j<row_size; ++j) { ... }`

Comment: I think this is not the issue, but this always better to check is malloc success or not.